# need to read an array of chars from a data file, I have a loop setup and it just outputs numbers not the chars I would expect

Tags: c, arrays, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define inputfile "C:\\Users\\FailedPilgrim\\Documents\\UNDPROG\\wind.txt"

/* Main function */
int main(void)
{
    /* Declare variables */
    char city_datatype[21];
    double wind_speeds [12][5], total_rows[12] ={0}, total_cols[5]={0}, 
    average_rows[12], average_cols[5];
    int i, j, nrows, ncols;
    FILE *input = NULL;

    /*Open input file*/
    input= fopen(inputfile, "r");   

    /*verify input file*/
    if (input==NULL)
    {
        printf ("\n\n\nERROR OPENING INPUT FILE.\n\n");
        printf ("\n\nPROGRAM TERMINATED...\n\n\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /*read title*/
    for (i=0; i<=21;i++)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%c", &city_datatype[i]);
        printf("%d",city_datatype[i]);
        ...
```

This is reading a data file that starts with the phrase "Centerville-WindSpeed"
My task is to read this into an array and print the array. Why does my code not work? My output is a bunch of seemingly random numbers

Comment: printf("%d",city_datatype[i]); because you are asking for integers. Use %c.

Comment: You are reading a character, and printing it as a decimal (i.e. ascii code of said character)?

Answer (score 2):

Your printf, at the end of the last loop, is printing your chars as integers via the "%d" format string.

If you want to print each city_datatype as characters, try to use "%c" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is

```
printf("%d",city_datatype[i]);//It will print ASCII value that's why
                              //you see some random number
```

change it to

```
printf("%c",city_datatype[i]);
```